# Getting an error in line player.PlaySync()

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting an error in line `player.PlaySync()`.I am a creating `.wav` file. It is showing me an error

> "The file located at
>   D:\Seo-app\SEO-Automation-Page-Generation.APP\SEO-Automation-Page-Generation.APP\Download\Autoplay.wav
>   is not a valid wave file."

```
var response = client.SynthesizeSpeech(input, voice, config);

int count = 1;
string virtualPath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("/Download/");
if (!Directory.Exists(virtualPath))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(virtualPath);
string fullPath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("/Download/Autoplay.wav");
string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullPath);
string extension = Path.GetExtension(fullPath);
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);

while (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
{
    string tempFileName = string.Format("{0}({1})", fileNameOnly, count++);
    fullPath = Path.Combine(path, tempFileName + extension);
}

using (Stream output = System.IO.File.Create(fullPath))
{
    response.AudioContent.WriteTo(output);
}
using (SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer())
{
    player.SoundLocation = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("/Download/Autoplay.wav");

    player.PlaySync();
}
```

Comment: Well, is it a valid wave file or not?

Comment: if I am playing that file in my window it is playing well and showing me wave file but in exception, it is showing me wave file is not valid

Comment: Where are you copying the file from the D:\ drive to the virtual path?